# Use QGIS processing parameter in field calculator's formula

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-processing, python-script-tool

I built a python processing tool for QGIS where my goal is to use field calculator and multiply an existing field in a layer by a parameter (number) decided by the user.
I defined the parameter for the user inside the processing algorithm:

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
            name = self.Lane_Weight,
            description = self.tr('LaneWeight'),
            type = ProcessingParameterNumber.Double,
            defaultValue = 2.5,
            optional = True
        )
    )
```

My problem is that I can't understand how to call the `Lane_Weight` parameter in the field calculator **FORMULA**. This is what I have Tried (without any success):

```
    from qgis.processing import run as QgisRun
    QgisRun(
        "native:fieldcalculator", {
            'INPUT': my_layer,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'my_new_field',
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0, #float type
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 4,
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 4,
            'FORMULA': ' "MyFieldName" * parameters[self.Lane_Weight] ',  
            'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
        },
        context = context,
        feedback = feedback,
        is_child_algorithm = True
    )['OUTPUT']
```

*Working with QGIS 3.22.3*

Comment: Did you try to use the algorithm using the GUI and then in the log tab, to carefully compare the structure of the constructed dictionary of parameters with the one you are using in your code? This can give you some serious hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'FORMULA'` key in the dictionary of parameters passed to `QgisRun` gets a string as value.

In your example that is the verbatim `' "MyFieldName" * parameters[self.Lane_Weight] '`.

When executing the `native:fieldcalculator` algorithm, this string will end up as the field calculator's expression text and QGIS' expression evaluation engine will evaluate it.

For the evaluation engine the double quoted `"MyFieldName"` is special, it will know that this means "the feature's value in the `MyFieldName` column please". The `parameters[self.Lane_Weight]` however is not something it can understand as it knows no Python. So you'll need to retrieve that value in Python land and add it into the formula string before it gets passed to the expression engine.

You can get the value of your user parameter using various methods of the [QgsProcessingAlgorithm](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProcessingAlgorithm.html) class. In this case [QgsProcessingAlgorithm.parameterAsDouble()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProcessingAlgorithm.html#qgis.core.QgsProcessingAlgorithm.parameterAsDouble) probably makes most sense (I wonder if there is a simple "parameterAsDefined" method...). You can then use that value and insert it into the `FORMULA` string.

```
lane_weight = self.parameterAsDouble(parameters, self.Lane_Weight, context)
...
QgisRun(
    "native:fieldcalculator", {
        ...
        'FORMULA': f'"MyFieldName" * {lane_weight}',  # inserted via f-string
        ...
     },
     ...
)
```

Reference: [Parsing an input parameter to gdal:rastercalculator formula in QGIS 3.6 Python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323157/parsing-an-input-parameter-to-gdalrastercalculator-formula-in-qgis-3-6-python-s)

PS: Is your `self.Lane_Weight` really something to be used as parameter *name*? It sounds like a numeric value rather.

Comment: This is the answer, thank you very much !